Keeping user customization in CoolBar/ToolBar at restart
In Main Form I have a TCoolBar object that contains two TToolBar objects.
The order/position of the TToolBars can be changed by user (with mouse) but at restart of my application returns in original position. The same thing is for button customization in the TToolBar.
Is there a way to permit at user to persist at reboot:

the user-cutomizated position from user of TToolBars?
the user-cutomizated order of buttons in the TToolBars?

If yes, do you have an example?
I use Embarcadero C++ Builder 12.
Thank you a lot.
In the proprieties of TToolBar I saw CustomizeKeyName and CustomizeValueName but I don't know if are what works for me and I don't how to use its.
